# Proof that a conic is nonsingular if and only if it is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How could I go about proving that a conic in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ is non-singular if and only if it is irreducible. I have proven that any projective conic in $\mathbb{P}^{2}(\mathbb{C})$ is projectively equivalent to either $$X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 0 \:,\quad X^2 + Y^2 = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad X^2 = 0$$

however I'm unsure about where to go from here. My notes and knowledge is very limited and so I have very little to go on. I understand that the curve will be non-singular if each partial derivative is non-zero and that's about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two are reducible: $X^2+Y^2=(X+iY)(X-iY)$. All you have to
do is to prove the first is non-singular. But at a singular point,
all three partial derivatives vanish....

Comment: Ok so if I take $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 0$ then this is singular if and only if all partial derivatives at a point $P$ are zero. However this is only at the point $P = [0,0,0] \notin \mathbb{P}^{2}$. Is that it?

Comment: @Killuminati That's right --- so there is no singularity!

Comment: I love you right now... thank you so much!